# How to mark state of an airflow task as failed from its success callback?

Tags: python, airflow

**Can a task be marked failed from its "on_success_callback"**

#### Use case:

The task executes and logs some information.
I process these logs in "on_success_callback" of the task and based on logs, I want to mark the state of task as failed.

*I have tried raising an exception in "on_success_callback" but it just logs that "on_success_callback" failed and marks the task as success.*

This is the code for my airflow task, 
dag_utils is a python file which gives implementation of task_callback in which I process the logs:

```
airflow_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    bash_command = dag_utils.make_full_command(cmd),
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
    on_failure_callback = dag_utils.task_callback,
    on_success_callback = dag_utils.task_callback,
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can a task be marked failed from its "on_success_callback"? => No

Because they are callbacks after received status from task. [Prefer Airflow Code here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L930)

To suit your requirement, I suggest to have a new task upstream your `task1` to process logs from `task1` output. With this implementation you can easily mark it fail or success.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .

I was able to change the state of task from its success_callback as follows:
context['task_instance']=State.FAILED